Set the background colour of a view based off a gradient scale
Say I have a simple view like the following that displays a score between 1 and 10. What is the best approach to assign a gradient scale to a range of numbers (between 1 and 10), so that 10 would be green, 0.1 would be red and everything in between would be based off that gradient. At the moment I am doing something simple like the following but i'm sure there must be a better way?
func ratingColor(rating: Double) -> Color {
    if rating == 0 {
        return .gray
    } else if rating < 4 {
        return .red
    } else if rating > 7 {
        return .green
    } else {
        return .orange
    }
}

Text(String(scoreBetweenOneAndTen)) // 7.64
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
    .background(ratingColor(rating: scoreBetweenOneAndTen)) 


Hue to the rescue! With hue, it becomes really simple:
Text(String(scoreBetweenOneAndTen)) // 7.64
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
    .background(Color(hue: (scoreBetweenOneAndTen*12)/360, saturation: 1, brightness: 0.8))


Note: I found out that 0.8 brightness works the best. More than that is too bright.

I agree, 0.8 works best. This is the simplest solution and works best for my use case. Thanks!

One simple way is to do a simple linear interpolation of the RGB components:
func interpolateColor(color1: Color.Resolved, color2: Color.Resolved, value: Float) -> Color.Resolved {
    let r = lerp(min: color1.red, max: color2.red, value: value)
    let g = lerp(min: color1.green, max: color2.green, value: value)
    let b = lerp(min: color1.blue, max: color2.blue, value: value)
    return Color.Resolved(red: r, green: g, blue: b)
}

// this assumes value is between 0 and 1, so you would need to divide your number by 10 first
func lerp(min: Float, max: Float, value: Float) -> Float {
    min + value * (max - min)
}

Note that you should use Color.Resolved instead of Color, in order to get the RGB components.
Example usage:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var slider: Float = 0
    @Environment(\.self) var env
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Foo Bar Baz")
                .background(
                    interpolateColor(
                        color1: Color.green.resolve(in: env),
                        color2: Color.red.resolve(in: env),
                        value: slider
                    )
                )
            Slider(value: $slider)
        }
    }
}

In my opinion though, this doesn't always look nice, especially when the value is around 0.5.

You could apply the gradient as background to the text, but over a much larger size. Then offset the gradient according to the score and clip the result. If this is done vertically, the gradient over the height of the text is not perceivable.
I found it was necessary to apply either .compositingGroup() or .drawingGroup() to the background too, otherwise the gradient only worked over the height of the clipped shape.
Text(String(format: "%.2f", scoreBetweenOneAndTen)) // 7.64
    .frame(width: 200, height: 40)
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
    .background(alignment: .bottom) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(
                LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                        scoreBetweenOneAndTen > 0 ? .red : .gray,
                        scoreBetweenOneAndTen > 0 ? .green : .gray
                    ],
                    startPoint: .bottom,
                    endPoint: .top
                )
            )
            .frame(height: 10000)
            .offset(y: (scoreBetweenOneAndTen / 10) * (10000 - 40))
            .compositingGroup() // or .drawingGroup()
    }
    .clipped()



If you would like a particular score to have a particular color then you could always use an array of color stops to build the gradient instead. For example:
LinearGradient(
    stops: [
        .init(color: .red, location: 0),
        .init(color: .orange, location: 0.33),
        .init(color: .yellow, location: 0.67),
        .init(color: .green, location: 1)
    ],
    startPoint: .bottom,
    endPoint: .top
)

